# Enumeration literal vhdl is not of type

Tags: logic, vhdl, modelsim, quartus, ieee

I am currently designing a 4-bit ALU consisting of MUXES and Full Adders. I am just about finished but am running into a few errors regarding my test bench. I really appreciate any help on this! As you can tell, this error shows that I am still a beginner in VHDL.

Error: `Enumeration literal 'Z' is not of type ieee.std_logic_1164.std_logic_vector`

The Z is either 0 or 1 where I declare my input values.

My original module Code:

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

ENTITY lab2 IS
    PORT(A, B: IN bit_vector(3 downto 0);
            Cin,S1,S0: IN bit;
            Cout: OUT bit;
            F: OUT bit_vector(3 downto 0));
    End lab2;

ARCHITECTURE Structure of lab2  IS

    COMPONENT MUX_A IS
    PORT(A, S0, S1: IN bit;
            X: OUT bit);
    END COMPONENT;

    COMPONENT MUX_B IS
    PORT(B, S0, S1: IN bit;
            Y: OUT bit);
    END COMPONENT;

    COMPONENT Full_Adder
            PORT (A_IN,B_IN,Cin: IN bit;
            Cout, F: OUT bit);
    END COMPONENT;

SIGNAL A_OUT: bit_vector (3 downto 0); 
SIGNAL B_OUT: bit_vector (3 downto 0);
SIGNAL Cout1, Cout2, Cout3: bit; 

BEGIN

    MUXA0: MUX_A PORT MAP(A(0), S0, S1, A_OUT(0));
    MUXA1: MUX_A PORT MAP(A(1), S0, S1, A_OUT(1));
    MUXA2: MUX_A PORT MAP(A(2), S0, S1, A_OUT(2));
    MUXA3: MUX_A PORT MAP(A(3), S0, S1, A_OUT(3));

    MUXB0: MUX_B PORT MAP(B(0), S0, S1, B_OUT(0));
    MUXB1: MUX_B PORT MAP(B(1), S0, S1, B_OUT(1));
    MUXB2: MUX_B PORT MAP(B(2), S0, S1, B_OUT(2));
    MUXB3: MUX_B PORT MAP(B(3), S0, S1, B_OUT(3));

    Adder1_0: Full_Adder PORT MAP(A_OUT(0), B_OUT(0), Cin, Cout1, F(0));
    Adder1_1: Full_Adder PORT MAP(A_OUT(1), B_OUT(1), Cout1, Cout2, F(1));
    Adder1_2: Full_Adder PORT MAP(A_OUT(2), B_OUT(2), Cout2, Cout3, F(2));
    Adder1_3: Full_Adder PORT MAP(A_OUT(3), B_OUT(3), Cout3, Cout, F(3));


END Structure;
```

My Testbench Code thus far:

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

ENTITY testbench IS
END testbench;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF testbench IS
COMPONENT Lab2
    PORT(A, B: IN bit_vector(3 downto 0);
            Cin,S1,S0: IN bit;
            Cout: OUT bit;
            F: OUT bit_vector(3 downto 0));
END COMPONENT;

    --Declare inputs and initialize them
    SIGNAL A:bit_vector(3 downto 0);
    SIGNAL B:bit_vector(3 downto 0);
    SIGNAL Cin:bit;
    SIGNAL S1:bit;
    SIGNAL S0:bit;

    --Declare outputs and initialize them 
    SIGNAL Cout:bit;
    SIGNAL F:bit_vector(3 downto 0);

BEGIN
UUT: Lab2 PORT MAP (
    A => A,
    B => B,
    Cin => Cin,
    S1 => S1,
    S0 => S0,
    Cout => Cout,
    F => F);

    stim_proc: process
BEGIN
    --Declare input values of A & B
    A <= '0';
    B <= '0';
    wait for 20 ns;
    A <= '0';
    B <= '1';
    wait for 20 ns;
    A <= '1';
    B <= '0';
    wait for 20 ns;
    A <= '1';
    B <= '1';
    wait for 20 ns;

    --Declare input values for Cin
    Cin <= '0';
    wait for 20 ns;
    Cin <= '1';
    wait for 20 ns;

    --Declare Input values for S1 & S0
    S1 <= '0';
    S0 <= '0';
    wait for 20 ns;
    S1 <= '0';
    S0 <= '1';
    wait for 20 ns;
    S1 <= '1';
    S0 <= '0';
    wait for 20 ns;
    S1 <= '1';
    S0 <= '1';
    wait for 20 ns;

END process;

END;
```

Comment: Uhm this code does not seen right. Your instantiating `testbench` as UUT in the architecture of `testbench`. Also, you're only showing us the test bench. Where the original component?

Comment: And why are you including the std_logic libraries when you are not using them?? Google some examples of vhdl code please.

Comment: JHBonarius, thanks for catching that UUT mistake, resolved one error. I'll upload my module now. Altogether, I have Four HDL files: Mux_A, Mux_B, Full_Adder, Lab2(combines all three HDL files to connect to one circuit) and testbench.

Comment: I realized not too long ago that the libraries I added are not useful in anyway for me on this testbench. I have made the corrections on this issue, thanks

Comment: You need to decide if you want to use `bit` and `bit_vector` with bit values `0, 1` or `std_logic` and `std_logic_vector` with bit values `U, 0, 1, H, L, Z, -, W, X`.

Comment: bit and bit_vector seem to be the most useful for me in this situation as I can input one bit values to my S1 & S0(Selects on MUXES) along with Cin(Full Adders). Then for my 4 bit inputs, I can use bit_vector for my A & B(Input for MUXES). Definitely correct me if I am wrong or if there is a "better" way to declare my input values.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right testbench in your project? There is no character literal 'Z' present in your shown testbench nor it's edit history. However you are attempting to associate an actual character literal to a formal bit_vector, e.g.: `A <= '0';` where `SIGNAL A:bit_vector(3 downto 0);` producing errors.  If you eventually need to do bit_vector arithmetic  use context clause `library ieee; use ieee.numeric_bit.all;` and conversions between bit_vector and numeric_bit.unsigned or `library ieee; use ieee.numeric_bit_unsigned.all;` (-2008).

Comment: (And to cure that example error in the port map association element instead use `A <= "0000",` or `A => (others => '0'),` where you provide a value for each element of A.)